# Authorize redirection loop with FOSOAuth2 and FOSUser

Tags: oauth-2.0, symfony

I'm trying to make FOSUserBundle work with FOSOAuthServerBundle
, and I'm struggling with `oauth_authorize`, getting a 302 redirection loop.

Here is what I have in my `security.yml` (simplified):

```
firewalls:
    oauth_authorize:
      pattern:    ^/oauth/v2/auth
      form_login:
        provider: fos_userbundle
        check_path: /oauth/v2/auth/login_check
        login_path: /oauth/v2/auth/login

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/oauth/v2/auth/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

I have to specify the `login_path` because the default `/login` doesn't match `oauth_authorize` pattern.

I've added the `/oauth/v2/auth/login` route in my bundle, but even with a dummy controller, it's never called. I just get 302 redirections until Firefox says it's enough.

Someone in the [comments here](http://blog.logicexception.com/2012/04/securing-syfmony2-rest-service-wiith.html) suggested to add `$` at the end of the pattern regex, but then the routes doesn't match.

The log gives me:

> security.INFO: An AuthenticationException was thrown; redirecting to authentication entry point. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException(code: 0): A Token was not found in the TokenStorage. at /home/arthur/PhpstormProjects/rss-api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php:53)"} []

Am I missing something?

EDIT: symfony 3.0 and oauth-server-bundle 1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was indeed missing something, the anonymous directive which prevents the firewall to block the access.

```
firewalls:
    oauth_authorize:
      pattern:    ^/oauth/v2/auth
      form_login:
        provider: fos_userbundle
        check_path: /oauth/v2/auth/login_check
        login_path: /oauth/v2/auth/login
      anonymous: true
```